# Как переделать программу под обработку строки

Tags: c, строки, обработка, обработка-данных

Есть код со следующей функцией: 
1) Пользователь вводит числа через пробел
2) Программа распознает, какое это число (16-ричное или 10-ричное)
3) Программа ищет, являются ли числа центральными многоугольными
4) Выводит сообщение в зависимости от того, все, несколько или ни одного не удовлетворяют требованию.

Как переделать программу не под ввод пользователя, а под обработку уже имеющейся строки? Я уже кучу вариантов перепробовал, все не то. Пожалуйста, помогите! Заранее спасибо.

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char s[256], *p;
    int c;
    int *a = NULL, i = 0, j, dis, x, d = 0, b = 0, elem;
    p = s;
    printf("input str: ");
    c = getchar();
    *p++ = c;
    while (c != '\n') {
        c = getchar();
        if (c ==' ' || c=='\n' ) {
            *p = '\0'; /* add null terminator */
            if (s[0] == '0' && s[1] == 'x') {
                printf("%ld ", strtol(s, NULL, 16));
                a = (int*)realloc(a, (i + 1) * sizeof(int));
                a[i] = strtol(s, NULL, 16);
                i++;
            }
            else {
                printf("%ld ", strtol(s, NULL, 10));
                a = (int*)realloc(a, (i + 1) * sizeof(int));
                a[i] = strtol(s, NULL, 10);
                i++;
            }
            p = s;
        }
        else {
            *p++ = c;
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        dis = 1 - ( 4 * ((-2 * a[j]) + 2));
        x = (-1 + (sqrt(dis)))/2;
        if ((x + x * x) == 2 * a[j] - 2) {
            ++d;
        }
        else {
            ++b;

        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
    if (d > 0 && b == 0) printf("ALL\n");
    else if (d > 0 && b > 0) printf("SOME\n");
    else if (d == 0 && b > 0) printf("NONE\n");
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот это

```
c = getchar();
*p++ = c;
while (c != '\n') {
    c = getchar();
    if (c ==' ' || c=='\n' ) {
```

для строки char `s[]` как

```
int index = 0;
c = s[index++];
*p++ = c;
while (c) {
    c = s[index++];
    if (c ==' ' || c=='\0' ) {
```

Comment: Спасибо, переработаю!